# Bootstrap 3 *-down?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap 4 seems to have a *-down class. Is there any corresponding class for Bootstrap 3? This doesn't seem to cover devices <= sm:

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" class="visible-sm-down"/>
<img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" class="visible-md"/>
<img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" class="visible-lg"/>
```

This is my current solution:

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" class="visible-sm visible-xs"/>
<img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" class="visible-md"/>
<img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" class="visible-lg"/>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MkP88/177/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. In Bootstrap 3 if you want to make an element visible on two different widths you'll need to add two classes as you've done.

As your example already shows though, this only affects having to show exactly two different widths - as in Bootstrap 3 there are only four widths available. To show one width you'd only specify the one `visible-*` and to show three you'd instead use `hidden-*` to hide the width you aren't wanting to handle.

This is more of a problem in Bootstrap 4 as that introduces the `xl` width, meaning you'd need three classes instead of two, which is a lot more messy.